# Where can I find sax Commstudio for VB6?

Tags: vb6

From where can I download sax commstudio for a VB6 code, as I need to download it for VB6 code compilation.

Comment: From the official close reasons: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam._

Answer (score 1):

http://www.commstudio.com/support/download

Click the *CommStudio ActiveX* link and download.

Comment: thanks dude, but its a trail version, i have msdn subscription with license. But after putting in the license, the "Next" button goes disabled.Plz help